# Create new intent in background

Tags: android, android-intent

I am looking for a way to launch another app from within my app but so that the focus is not changed from my app to the app launched.

I.e currently I have the new app launched via a intent, however when this is carried out the new app is launched and becomes the app in view, I need it to be kept in the background with my app still in view.

The reason for this? 
I am developing an application for internal use that will act like a lock-screen to the device so although things must happen in the background the 'lock-screen' must always be on top.

I have done some research into intents and launching other apps but can not find anything about what I need.

Hope you can help thank you!

Currently the terminal is called like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("jackpal.androidterm", "jackpal.androidterm.RemoteInterface"));
    intent.setAction("jackpal.androidterm.RUN_SCRIPT");
    intent.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.iInitialCommand", cmdString);
```

The reason it needs to be running in the background is so that the app can run commands in terminal without the user having access, but then they 'unlock' the screen they need to then be able to view the terminal and what commands are being run etc

Comment: This project may be a starting point. It also describes what changed regarding Android versions and mentions apps which implement lock screen functionality for newer Android versions. You may want to have a look. http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/

Comment: @ZacPowell . I am having the same problem. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be possible, you will have to start a background `Service` that does the actual work and only launch the `Activity` you want to navigate to once your foreground `Activity` is finished. Depending on your architecture, you can store the `Activity` to call when your foreground `Activity` is finished and change it from the service. That way you will have your desire behaviour without having to actually call the `Activity`.

Comment: The activity I need to launch in the background is a terminal window (https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki) so the lockscreen will always be on top (At least until its unlocked) but the terminal will need to be running in the background.

Comment: Okay, you need to explain a bit more as to why the `Activity` has to be started in the background. If the user won't see the UI, then there's really no point in using an `Activity` for that

Comment: I'm pretty sure there will be a way to at least come pretty close to what @ZacPowell wants, even without a custom launcher (which might still be suitable given that it's an app for "internal use").

Comment: I have added how the activity is currently called, the terminal needs to be running and ready to use.

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach to the situation. If the app wants to run commands the user should not see (or manipulate), then it should definitely not input them using the UI of any `Activity`. You should skip the UI layer and call the resulting methods directly. If you are dead-set on that method, you should probably look into the methods mentioned by @421 and @ZacPowell

Comment: @Thrakbad the thing is that a user that does unlock the app does need to see what commands have been launched etc.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I don't know enough about your specific use-case and requirements, and the terminal `Activity` to think of a nice solution here, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can not startActivity in Background.Instead start the activity and minimise the activity(in your case this activity is of different application) using `moveTaskToBack(true);`

In your case, put a condition based on your intent and its params  and use `moveTaskToBack(true);` so that activity will be minimised only when your application launches.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from @Meher, in the intent for your current starting activity, you can add the flag FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND.
With this you get rid of the "blinking" effect (the one where your activity shows for one fraction of second while it discovers wether to go to background)